# What's the difference between es6 and es2015 in Typescript compiler option --libs

Tags: typescript

What's the difference between es6 and es2015 in Typescript compiler option (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) --libs ?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

None, they're just aliases to the same thing, and a remnant of a bad naming decision in the earlier days of JavaScript standardization.

`ES2015` is the same as `ES6`, and `ES2016` is the same as `ES7`. In the case of `--lib`, `ES2015` also allows some granularity with separate definition packages, but it's really just a naming convention.

Eventually it'll all be kept as `ES20xx` and we can pretend `ESx` never happened.